# How to select 3 of the latest value on "sum" column

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I want to get the latest "point_dttm" 3 value on "sum" column specific on the combination of "chart" and "equip" column

i have below a working code using max to get the latest 1 value on "sum" column specific on the combination of "chart" and "equip" column. What I want now is to get the 3 latest value. I've tried rownum <= 3 order by point_dttm asc but it only gives 3 values not considering the combination of "chart" and "equip" column.

```
select a.chart,a.equip,a.point_dttm,a.sum 
from spc_point a,
(select chart, equip, max(point_dttm) as point_dttm from spc_point 
where chart like 'TX%' 
and equip like 'MP%'
group by chart,equip) b

where b.equip = a.equip
and a.chart = b.chart
and a.point_dttm = b.point_dttm
order by a.equip asc
```

I want to get:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/st7c5.png)

but rownum <=3 will give you only this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8YqL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
SELECT chart,
   equip,
   point_dttm,
   SUM


FROM (SELECT a.chart,
               a.equip,
               a.point_dttm,
               a.SUM,
               RANK ()
               OVER (PARTITION BY a.chart, a.equip, a.point_dttm
                     ORDER BY a.SUM DESC)
                   rk
          FROM spc_point a)
 WHERE rk <= 3;
```